# Class function not changing member variable

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ and yesterday i did my first step with the OO (Object Oriented).
I made a programm that has a character class (Personnage), i made three variables for the character, vie, mana and degat.
I made also a function in the class which is attack and it should remove health from john, but when i show the health of john with another function i see 100, can someone help me please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
       class Personnage
    {
    public:
    void montrer()
    {
        cout << vie << endl;
    }
    void attaquer(Personnage john)
    {   
        vie = vie - degat;
        if (vie < 0)
        {
            vie = 0;
        }
    }
    private:
    int degat = 50;
    int vie = 100;
    int mana = 100;
    };
       int main
        {
        int action(0), degat;
        Personnage jack, john;
        cout << "What action do you want to do ?" << endl;
        cout << "1-Attack your ennemy." << endl;
        cout << "2-Take some life" << endl;
        cout << "3-Take some mana." << endl;
        cin >> action;
        switch(action)
        case '1':
        jack.attaquer(john);
        john.montrer();

        return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must do "case 1" instead of " case '1' " because your variable is integer. However, this wont solve your problem, and you will still see john's state unaffected by the call of the method "attaquer". Why? because method attaquer is invoked on the personnage Jack, not John. If you want the method to change the health of the attacked Paersonnage, not the attacking one, you should make it like this:

```
 void attaquer(Personnage& victime) // notice the &, pass by reference
    {   
        victime.vie -= degat;
        if (victime.vie < 0)
        {
            victime.vie = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, it can also work by inverting john with jack and vice-versa.
But i don't understand what i doesn't work that way too, i got inspired by a code that i found an online C++ course, thank you ;)

Comment: Welcome Mehdi. I still advice you to MAKE SURE you understand why it has to be that way before proceeding further. As we say in French, this is the " B. A. BA " of C++ :)

Comment: @MehdiBmm please accept the answer so that this topic can be closed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
void attaquer(Personnage john)
{   
    vie = vie - degat;
    if (vie < 0)
    {
        vie = 0;
    }
}
```

`vie` and `degat` both refer to the fields of the object the method was called from. You call `attaquer` from `jack`, so `jack`'s data changes. You then call `john.montrer()`, which will show `john`'s untarnished data.

I assume you intended that `attaquer` affect the `Personnage` passed to it. To alter the passed parameter:

```
void attaquer(Personnage john)
{   
    john.vie = john.vie - degat;
    if (john.vie < 0)
    {
        john.vie = 0;
    }
}
```

You have to specify that you want to use a *different* object's data. This, however, is not a complete solution because `void attaquer(Personnage john)` takes a `Personnage` by value. This means it copies the object you give it, and that new copy disappears at the end of the function. Make it a reference like:

```
void attaquer(Personnage& john)
```

This will affect the original object you sent to the function.

Of course, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576264/4756309) answer points out that your switch statement is comparing an integer to a character `1` and `'1'` are two different values.